# Large Decimal Number Parse

Tags: c#

I know this has some answers but not exactly what I'm looking for.

I have an application with a custom scripting language for file formats where numbers can be added, subtracted, etc...

One part will produce decimal,hex conversion and I was able to use the BigInteger class which is nice because I don't have to worry about large values.

For math operations though I am stuck using a Decimal and I would like to know if anyone has any suggestions for something like BigInteger that I can use for Decimal.  I have seen BigRational but it doesn't look like it will fit.

Here is the code snippet where it's used.  The asdecimal probably looks stupid but it's just decimal parse where zero is returned if invalid.

```
private string Subtract(StringReader reader, string text)
    {
        string value = reader.ReadToEnd();
        value = Evaluate(value);

        var a = text.AsDecimal();
        var b = value.AsDecimal();

        return (a - b).ToString();
    }
```

To make this more clear.  This function can handle any conceivable situation because of BigInteger

```
private string HexToDec(string value)
    {
        try
        {
            var input = this.Evaluate(value);
            var number = BigInteger.Parse(input, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            return number.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "INVALID_HEX_NUMBER";
        }
    }
```

I would like subtract tot be as flexible.  If it's not possible, that is fine.

Comment: so how can I load a large decimal into big rational?  I don't see a parse function.  Seems like you can only used if you know the fraction.

Comment: `decimal` goes pretty large to start with - what precision and scale do you need?

Comment: precision will not be high, I just want to make the program as flexible as possible.  I can't know what someone might use as inputs for these functions.  Large whole number portion is more likely though.

Comment: Larger than 10^28? I would think carefully about your real requirements before you go overboard.

Comment: I here you, check out my edit to see where i'm coming from

Comment: No, that doesn't really answer the point I'm making. What's more important: getting something working that will handle every *likely* situation, or spending longer trying to find something that will handle every *conceivable* situation? What if someone wants to include a number which would take more space than your computer has memory or even disk? I can conceive of that, and your current `BigInteger` code wouldn't handle it - but I don't think it's actually a problem. The question is whether the limitations of `decimal` are actually significant in your case.

Comment: I understand your point.  The point I'm trying to make is to let the program be as flexible as possible.  I have the thing implemented with decimal but when someone enters 9999999999999999999999999999999 it's going to have issues.  May not happen but just wanted to see if there was an easy solution like BigInteger gives me.